# Ore Condition Implies a Partial Mapping

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to prove a theorem (2.2.9) from *Combinatorics: The Rota Way* and am having difficulty doing so.

A relation $R : S \to X$ has a partial matching of size $|S| − d$ if and only if $R$ satisfies the Ore condition: for every subset $A$ in $S$, $|R(A)| \geq |A| − d$

I defined a set $D$ such that $D$ is disjoint from $X$ and has size $d$ and define $R':S \to X \cup D$ as the relation $R \cup (S \times D)$. Therefore, I would need to prove the following statements:

"$R′$ satisfies the Hall condition if and only if $R$ satisfies the Ore condition" and "$R′$ has a matching if and only if $R$ has a partial matching of size $|S| − d$"

While I was able to prove the reverse direction of the first statement, I am having trouble with the forward direction and would appreciate a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ll need to show:

If $R′$ satisfies the Hall condition, then $R$ satisfies the Ore condition.

The Hall condition says that for all $A ⊆ S, |R′(A)| ≥ |A|$.
Since $R′ = R ∪ (S × D)$, this means $|R(A)| + |A ∩ D| ≥ |A|$.
But $A$ and $D$ are disjoint, so $|A ∩ D| = 0$. Therefore, $|R(A)| ≥ |A|$, which is the Ore condition for $R$.

So you've proved the forward direction of the first statement. The second statement follows directly from this, since having a matching in $R′$ is equivalent to satisfying the Hall condition, and having a partial matching of size $|S| - d$ in $R$ is equivalent to satisfying the Ore condition.

Comment: I've done it for you this time, but in the future, you're going to want to format your math using MathJax (it's somewhat of an important rule here). For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).